# TSQL - View w/programmatical joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, view, data-warehouse

I need some help streamlining a DWH implementation.

Presently we have a fact table, which contains 17 dimensions which are varchars within the fact (I didn't design this).  We have re-worked our entire ETL process to add a single dimension id value which is a reference to a new snowflake - which represents the combination of the 17 values.  We have called this the "matrix id".  All of our ETL processes are now keying off this ID rather than the 17 varchars, and the merge performance has been amazing even though we are still writing the varchars.

We are now looking to do away with the 17 varchar values (stop writing, and drop columns from fact).

A rough outline of our tables (omitting useless info):

- `dbo.factPerformance: ifactID, sMarketCode, sListCode, sBatchCode..., iDimMatrixID(FK)`
- `dbo.Matrix: iDimMatrixID(PK), iDimMarketCodeID(FK), iDimListCodeID(FK), iDimBatchCodeID(FK)...`
- `dbo.dimMarketCode: iDimMarketCodeID(PK), sMarketCode`
- `dbo.dimListCode: iDimListCodeID(PK), sListCode`
- `dbo.dimBatchCode: iDimBatchCodeID(PK), sBatchCode`

And so on...

So this new `iDimMatrixID` is a reference to the 17 possible other foreign keys. These values are unique. There will never be two entries in any of the dimensions with duplicate values.

Now to the fun part... 
Since we have so many processes that use the fact table the way it is, and are built with those varchars present, we need a way to keep them present -- even though they aren't.  So we are looking to rename the fact, and build a view (with old fact name) that joins the fact to the new dimensions so the resulting view looks like the old fact table... but this is inefficient, since 75%+ of our reports don't care about these 17 values -- if we don't have any of the varchar's in our select/where/group by -- then why bother joining to the dimensions at all.

So my question is this... and I'm pretty sure the answer is no.

Is there any conceivable way of designing a view that is "intelligent" enough to omit the join to dimMatrix, and all sub-dimensions if the select/where/group by do not reference any of the 17 strings.

Like I said, I'm pretty sure it can't be done, but we want to be sure before we head down the path of modifying our reporting procedures to dynamically join only those dimensions that are required.

Comment: No and if it does exist, it's not worth it.  K.I.S.S.

Comment: As I suspected.  Thank you for the confirmation Dan.